# How can I determine the position of my subplot label?

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I'm trying to label both of my subplots using Python and locate the text to the upper right corner:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, sharex=True, figsize = (16,18))
plt.xticks(fontsize=15)
...
axs[0].text(0.9,0.1,r'$E_b$',verticalalignment='top',fontsize = 30)
```

The last line is referenced from [matplotlib.axes.Axes.text](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.text.html) . I've read some examples but I'm still not pretty sure how I can determine the appropriate values of x and y to make my label to the upper right corner? The current values (0,9 and 0.1) do not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing this:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, sharex=True, figsize = (16,18))
plt.xticks(fontsize=15)

plt.text(0.67, 0.9, 'I am 0.70, 0.90', fontsize=14, transform=plt.gcf().transFigure)
plt.text(0.67, 0.48, 'I am 0.70, 0.48', fontsize=14, transform=plt.gcf().transFigure)
```

Will give you this:
[image]

```
axs[0].text(...)
```

will give you the text coordinate relative to axs[0]. I guess what you want is to have figure coordinate instead of axis coordinate. For that you need

```
transform=plt.gcf().transFigure
```

and just `plt.text(...)` so you don't need to specify the subplots.

Figure coordinate `0,0` is bottom left and `1,1` is upper right.